# How can I dismiss tableviewController that view added by method addsubview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I designed a viewController,and used keyWindow add its view,now I add a tableview on view of viewcontroller and display it  .
    How can I disselect one cell and dismiss the tableviewController of the tableview?

Comment: It is better, if you add a little bit of your code to show what you mean. It will help to get the answer faster.

Comment: You get out of bed and I'm fall asleep,worse,My mac  in the classroom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you asking, but if you want to remove tableView:

```
[tableView removeFromSuperview];
```

If you want to dismiss tableViewController:

```
[tableViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I designed a viewcontroller and add a tableview on viewcontroller' view , in the delegate mehtod didSelectRowAtIndexPath  I write [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil], I hope to select one cell and go back viewcontroller

Comment: and whats the problem?

Comment: Now I can't go back viewcontroller from tableview

Comment: TableView isn't viewController, you need at least 2 viewControllers here, the one with tableView and the one thats going to be shown after you dismiss viewController with tableView

Comment: I have talbeviewcontroller control this tableview ,tell me your email,I send my demo show you what I say

Comment: I also want to see the demo. Please, publish here a piece of trouble code.

Comment: Yes post some code here in your question, so other people can see too